# Silverlight 4 toolkit DataForm including blank items when browsing through collection

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-toolkit

I have a simple dataform created that reads address information.
The address information is stored across multiple tables: Address, City, Province, Country.  To simplify this question, I will only refer to Address and City.
I'm accessing the data through WCF RIA Services context.  My query in the Service is:

```
public IQueryable<Address> GetAddresses()
    {
        return from Ad in ObjectContext.Addresses
               .Include("City")
               // .Include("City.Province")
               // .Include("City.Province.Country")
               where Ad.AddressID == 10
               select Ad;
    }
```

To help with my debugging, I've limited the result set to one address (where Ad.AddressID ==10).  In the Service metadata the city table is included:

```
        [Include]
        public City City { get; set; }
```

My DataForm's read only template looks like:

```
      <dataFormToolkit:DataForm.ReadOnlyTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <dataFormToolkit:DataField Label="Street Address" >
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StreetAddress, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </dataFormToolkit:DataField>

                <dataFormToolkit:DataField Grid.Row="1" Label="City" >
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=City.CityName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </dataFormToolkit:DataField>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dataFormToolkit:DataForm.ReadOnlyTemplate>
```

Now, when I debug my DataForm, I'm expecting just the 1 address record to display.  But it actually brings back 2 records: the expected address record and the linked City record.  The first record that shows up is the address including the linked city.  The second shows up as blank, but when breaking into the code, the DataForm's CurrentItem shows that it's the City record linked to the first address.

How do I restrict the items in the DataForm to display and browse through just those from the Address table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was loading 'AllEntities' in my code behind.

```
dfAdd.ItemsSource = addressDataLoadResult.AllEntities;
```

So the fix was to change the ItemsSource to only load 'Entities'.  This restricted my collection to Address objects only.